# Indy SNMP and C++ Builder XE3

Tags: c++, c++builder, snmp, indy

I'm trying to use Indy SNMP component but is having problems

The following code

```
try
{
    TIdSNMP* client         = new TIdSNMP();
    String host     = "192.168.123.123";
    String mib      = "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0";
    Log(lInfo) << "Test simple SNMP call on server: " << host;
    client->Host           = host;
    client->BoundIP        = "192.168.123.1";
    client->Community      = "public";
    client->ReceiveTimeout = 1000;

    client->Query->Clear();
    client->Query->PDUType = PDUGetRequest;
    client->Query->MIBAdd(mib,"");

    if (client->SendQuery()) 

      //...
    }
    else
    {
        Log(lInfo) << "*** Query not sent *** ";
    }
  delete client;
}
catch (const Exception & ex)
{
    Log(lInfo) << Mylog(L"ERROR [%s] ", ex.Message.c_str());
}
```

keep returning false on the SendQuery line, while using the snmpget client in a terminal gives proper result

```
>/Users/matsk:\> snmpget -v 2c -c public 192.168.123.123  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: Watchdog 15
```

where

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: Watchdog 15
```

is an expected return string from a temperature measuring device.
Or using version 1

```
>/Users/matsk:\> snmpget -v 1 -c public 192.168.123.123  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: Watchdog 15
```

I should add to the question that the device is connected to the local computer using a Ethernet -> USB dongle and is on a different 'subnet' than my regular internet connection. I'm not sure if that may add to Indy's behavior?

Doing a ipconfig /all gives for the relevant ethernet adapter, as suggested by Remy L.

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Linksys USB3GIGV1
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 94-10-3E-B7-D7-0A
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bc9f:3659:9f91:2627%24(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.123.1(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 412356670
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-70-32-91-D8-CB-8A-BC-E5-B
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

from where I used BoundIP = 192.168.123.1

However, SendQuery() still returns false.

I copied some code from this post: 
[Indi TIdSNMP : How use SendQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867499/indi-tidsnmp-how-use-sendquery)

Using Wireshark and a filter gives one line

```
63  47.723731   192.168.123.1   192.168.123.123 SNMP    82  get-request 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
```

Interestingly, when using snmpget I get

```
476 182.830210  192.168.123.1   192.168.123.123 SNMP    83  get-request 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
```

Only difference is that the Length record is being 83, instead of 82 for the request using Indy. Not sure if that helps figuring out whats going on?

Comment: What does "keep giving negative result" mean?

Comment: `client->Query->MIBAdd(mib,"");` Given that your `mib` variable is actually an OID, this seems strange. Either Indy SNMP doesn't understand basic SNMP terminology, or you're using the function wrong...

Comment: @Totte: You shouldn't be calling `client->Active = true` at all, but if you do, you should be setting the `client->Host` beforehand.  Also, since your device is on a particular network, you should consider setting the `client->BoundIP` to the IP address of the network adapter that is connected to that same network. And `SendQuery()` can't "give negative result" since its return value is a `bool`.  Also, your `snmpget` example is using SNMPv2c, but `TIdSNMP` only supports SNMPv1.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `TIdSNMP` understands OIDs, and Totte's use of `MIBAdd()` is correct.  `TIdSNMP` encompasses OIDs in a "MIB" collection, which includes the OID, value, and value type of each item being requested/responded.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's... not what a MIB is. That's a set of varbinds.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm aware of what a MIB really is (I have a product I wrote that uses a custom MIB for defining SNMP traps for app events). But I didn't write `TIdSNMP`, only maintain it (it actually originated in Synapse and was adapted into Indy. This "MIB" usage still exists in Synapse's current SNMP code).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I never claimed that you wrote `TIdSNMP`. I merely pointed out that whoever the author is doesn't appear to understand what a MIB is. You said they understand OIDs; I object, due to this function naming, as discussed above.

Comment: Either way, the `mib` name _is_ strange. Glad to hear the OP's function usage is logically correct, though.

Comment: I would bet you're on the money that the OP is expecting their v1 lib to work with a v2c-only agent. (Many agents are backward compatible, but most may only operate in one mode at a time)

Comment: @Totte: Did you try it with a SNMPv1 agent, as discussed above?

Comment: Yeah, just added the result to the question. Seem to work fine.

Comment: Well, worth a try :)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the tools required to reproduce here, but if you are able to get a quick Wireshark capture of the attempt, I can probably tell you what's going on. Please include a capture of the successful v1 test using `snmpget`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I did install wireshark but seem not to be able to capture anything!? Need to figure out why that is..

Comment: @Totte: Make sure you selected the right network adaptor, and filter so that only UDP port 161 traffic is captured.

Comment: I didn't previously spot the "exception text" indicated in comments in your code.

Comment: Got wireshark enabled for the adapter and captured traffic using filter udp.port == 161

Comment: Actually, those exceptions occured when I used wrong BindIP. With the code above, I only get SendQuery() returning false, with no exceptions.

Comment: I don't see your comments unless you `@notify` me. Do you want to put the packet captures somewhere so I can see?

Comment: Although, thinking about it, since with v1 there is no response packet, I don't really know what I was expecting to see in a packet capture. If `SendQuery` is returning false in v1 it must be failing before sending anything out (there's no way it could determine that something it _did_ send had failed en route or in the manager)